# Want to show how many PDF files in a folder

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngFileCount As Long

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim folderpath
folderpath = InputBox("N:\Files", "Folder Path")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderpath)
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & " are:"

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If UCase$(Right$(objFile.Name, 4)) = ".PDF" Then
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = Replace$(UCase$(objFile.Name), ".PDF", "")
        Z = Z + 1
        MsgBox objFolder.Count.Z & ": The total number file in folder: "
    End If
Next

If Z = 0 Then
       MsgBox "No PDF Files found"
End If

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What and Where is the error?  Please put an explanation of the error and on which line it occurs.

Comment: MsgBox objFolder.Count.Z & ": The total number file in folder: " here

Comment: Edit you post instead of putting additional information into comments.

Comment: Not working objFolder.Count & ": The total number file in folder: Object doesn't support this property and MsgBox Z & ": The total number file in folder: " just show only one count at one click then i have click ok again then it will increase count, not show the total PDF files count.

Comment: See my answer, I've fixed both problems for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngFileCount As Long
Dim Z as Long

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim folderpath As String
folderpath = InputBox("N:\Files", "Folder Path")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderpath)
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & " are:"

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If UCase$(Right$(objFile.Name, 4)) = ".PDF" Then
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = Replace$(UCase$(objFile.Name), ".PDF", "")
    Z = Z + 1

    End If
Next
If Z = 0 Then

    MsgBox "No PDF Files found"

Else

    MsgBox "The total number of files in folder: " & Z

End If
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

I moved the MsgBox outside the loop so you only see it once with the total.

Also the property `objFolder.Count.Z` doesn't exist, you just want the variable `Z` which stores the count of your PDF files.

Comment: Error on: object doesn't support the property or method

Comment: You need to tell us what line you get the error on!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function to get the number of files

```
Function numberOfFiles(ByVal dirName As String, ByVal mask As String) As Long
    On Error GoTo Catch

    Dim maskName As String
    maskName = dirName & mask

    With CreateObject("wscript.shell")
        numberOfFiles = UBound(Split(.exec("cmd /c Dir """ & maskName & """ /b/a").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)) - 1
    End With

    Exit Function

Catch:
    numberOfFiles = 0

End Function
```

Test it with

```
Sub testIt()
    Debug.Print numberOfFiles("D:\user\examples\", "*.pdf")
End Sub
```

Your code changes to

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngFileCount As Long
Dim Z As Long

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim folderpath As String
folderpath = InputBox("N:\Files", "Folder Path")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderpath)

ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & " are:"

Z = numberOfFiles(folderpath, "*.PDF")

If Z = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No PDF Files found"
Else
    MsgBox "The total number of files in folder: " & Z
End If

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

and simply include the numberOfFiles function just below it.